# Nodej.js to force client to send Cookie in a request header

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, session-cookies

I'm having a micro service written in Node.js (express) and there is an authentication policy/logic implemented.

When I login into a portal and call url to my microservice directly (from browser), there is always sent *Cookie* as a part of request header.

Unfortunately when I test microservice in portal environment, no *Cookie* is sent. 
Is it possible to force client to open some iframe or popup to obtain *session info/Cookie* if missing?

Comment: Sorry, are you not receiving cookie in your back-end service? Or it's not getting sent by the your front-end. Usually front-end cookie data can be sent in request header.

Comment: @VPaul Hi, well, cookie data are not sent in request header from a frontend and because of that I'm not able to work with them on a backend side. Unfortunately, I have no control of a frontend part, my backend service is just registered there so I was wondering if there is a way how to force fronted to add cookie..

Comment: Hmm, that would be tricky. Not sure as I don't know the complete application flow.